# Trivial default constructor can't be constexpr?

Tags: c++, constructor, constexpr

It looks like the C++ standard currently prevents trivial default constructors from being constexpr (if there are any non-static member variables), because a trivial default constructor must do nothing, but a constexpr constructor must initialize everything.  This, unfortunately, prevents the type from being a POD type.

Is there any workaround that would allow a class type to have a default constructor that can be used in constexpr code without making the class non-POD?

I could work around it by adding a redundant parameter to the constructor so that constexpr code could use a non-default constructor, but that seems rather dirty, especially because in the cases I care about, the initialized values are unnecessary and will all be written-over in later code, so I'd prefer a trivial default constructor.  For example:

```
struct A {
    int a;

    // Non-default constructors necessitate an explicit default
    // constructor if default constructor is to exist
    constexpr A(int b) : a(b) {}

#if 1 // non-POD
    // constexpr default constructor must initialize everything,
    // but this makes A non-POD.
    constexpr A() : a(0) {}
#else // Workaround
    A() = default;
    struct UnnecessaryClass {};
    constexpr A(UnnecessaryClass) : a(0) {}
#endif
};
constexpr void someConstexprFunction(ClassThatADoesntKnowAbout& t) {
#if 1 // non-POD
    A a;             // I'd prefer this not be initialized yet,
#else // Workaround
    A a(A::UnnecessaryClass());
#endif
    t.initializeA(a) // because it's initialized here.
    // It doesn't make a difference when it's run at compile-time,
    // but the redundant initialization is rather unfortunate if it's
    // done at run-time.
}
void someNonConstexprFunction() {
    A *pa = new A[1000000]; // array is redundantly initialized in non-POD case
    ... // Other downsides of non-POD types, too
}
```

Comment: Instead of a C-style array you could use a `std::vector` which doesn't have to initialize all objects at once. It is also possible to make `A a = t.initializeA();` work, if you modify the other class. Now you are just fighting the language.

Answer (score 5):

Update: Trivial default initialization can be constexpr since C++20: [wg21.link/P1331R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf)

> This paper proposes permitting default initialization for trivially default constructible types in constexpr contexts while
> continuing to disallow the invocation of undefined behavior. In short, so long as uninitialized values are not read from, such
> states should be permitted in constexpr in both heap and stack allocated scenarios.

---

A Trivial constructor can't be constexpr because the result of initialising with a trivial constructor is an uninitialised value.

Illustration: What should the ::value of AVal be in this case?

```
struct A { int a; }

constexpr A a;
using AVal = std::integral_constant<int, a.a>;
```

There's no answer.

Comment: In an ideal world, I would hope that case would be a compile error, because it's clearly not initialized before use, (unless you count the automatic zero-initialization of POD global variables, but I try not to rely on that).  However, if the variable were provably initialized before being used, I really wish that it were valid.

Comment: @NeilDickson Well, if the variable is provably initialized before being used, such as in `constexpr A a{55};`, then this code snippet works as expected. And if it is not initialized, such as in this case, the compiler emits error. I am writing another answer, will post it in a few moments.

Comment: I said and meant "initialized", not "non-trivially constructed".  In the case of `A a; a = 5; functionCall(a);` it's easily provable that `a` is initialized before being passed to `functionCall`, even though it was trivially constructed.  Even Java can identify in simple cases whether or not something's initialized before use; if it can't prove it, it gives a compile error, but if it can prove that it's initialized before use, it doesn't error.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can't you use a trivial constructor in a `constexpr` context, you can't trivially construct built-in types, either.

`constexpr` evaluation implements a limited subset of C++, which doesn't include uninitialized values. So they are forbidden.

The problem may not be that it's difficult to get a POD class, but that PODs don't do what you want.

Comment: I want the class to have the advantages of being a POD type, while still being able to be used in a reasonable fashion in constexpr code.  Ideally, I'd even be able to tell the compiler that it can use a register to pass the class around and operate on it when possible, because it fits in one, but GCC, Clang, and Visual C++ all seem to have trouble figuring out that they can.

Comment: Since all constexpr evaluation happens at compile time, initializing a member before it's reassigned costs nothing — as long as it's really a constant expression. Still, the compiler should see that the initialization is unused and remove it. Just write {} and don't worry. Promoting a class value to a register is more complicated and depends on whether a pointer or reference is taken.